# Consulta para agrupar y filtrar por últimas fechas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla que tiene el siguiente formato (int, int, DateTime)

> ```
> Id  |  IdOperacion  |  Fecha
>  1  |            1  |  08/03/2021 10:00:00.00
>  2  |            2  |  08/03/2021 10:10:00.00
>  3  |            3  |  08/03/2021 10:20:00.00
>  4  |            1  |  08/03/2021 11:00:00.00
>  5  |            2  |  08/03/2021 11:10:00.00
>  6  |            3  |  08/03/2021 11:20:00.00
> ```

He tratado de obtener las últimas fechas para que quede la tabla asi:

> ```
> Id  |  IdOperacion  |  Fecha
>  4  |            1  |  08/03/2021 11:00:00.00
>  5  |            2  |  08/03/2021 11:10:00.00
>  6  |            3  |  08/03/2021 11:20:00.00
> ```

Sacando las operaciones con ultima fecha pero al ser variable no se como realizarlo:

```
SELECT Id, IdOperacion, Fecha FROM Tabla WHERE Fecha >= Convert(datetime, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay probablemente varias opciones para gestionar tu pregunta. Yo te propongo una basada en formatear la fecha para que solo contenga la fecha y la hora (sin minutos y segundos) y usar esto para filtrar los datos.

La primera parte es obtener la fecha solo con la hora. Para eso usamos `convert`:

```
convert(char(10), horainicio, 112) + ' ' + convert(char(2), horainicio, 108)
```

la primera parte devuelve la fecha como `yyyymmdd`, y la segunda devuelve la hora en formato `hh:mm:ss`. Pero como en la conversion usamos `char(2)`, obtenemos solo los dos primeros caracteres, es decir, la hora. El resultado que nos devuelve es algo asi:

```
20210308   10
```

Una vez resuelto ese problema, tenemos que obtener cual es la fecha/hora mayor que hay en nuestra tabla. Esto es sencillo: simplemente ordenamos por la fecha de forma descendente y  nos quedamos con el primer resultado:

```
select top 1 convert(char(10), fecha, 112)
+ ' ' + convert(char(2), fecha, 108) as fechamax
from Tabla
order by fechamax desc
```

El ultimo paso sería obtener las filas de la tabla cuya fecha convertida coincida con el dato de esta subconsulta:

```
select * from Tabla
where convert(char(10), fecha, 112)+ ' ' + convert(char(2), fecha, 108) =  
( select top 1 convert(char(10), fecha, 112)
+ ' ' + convert(char(2), fecha, 108) as fechamax
from Tabla
order by fechamax desc)
```

Comment: Justo con esto puedo obtener los ultimos registros realizados en una hora, en mi caso es lo mas optimo gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Partiremos el problema en dos. Primero obtenemos la última fecha por de cada elemento utilizando la función de agregación `MAX()`, luego uniremos el resultado (una fila por idOperacion) con la consulta de la tabla, obteniendo solo el último valor.

```
SELECT a.Id, a.IdOperacion, b.FechaMax
FROM Tabla a
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT IdOperacion , MAX(Fecha) as FechaMax
   FROM Tabla
   GROUP BY IdOperacion 
) b on a.IdOperacion = b.IdOperacion
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero cierto que erré en no comentar que quería tan solo los últimos registros del total, pero para una global de todos los registros la tuya es la correcta